# How to sort the options of the dropdown attribute in magento 2

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.3.1, sort, select

I am using the following code to get the options of the select attribute.

Now I want to get the options that should be ordered alphabetically.

**file.php**

```
$eavConfig = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
    $attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

    $optionsExists = array();

    foreach($options as $option) {
        $optionsValues[] = $option['value'];
        $optionsExists[] = $option['label'];
    }

    return $optionsExists;
```

I am using the above code. Can anyone guide magentoe2

Answer (score 1):

You may just use some php function to sort arrays like ksort or usort

Here you have an array sorting functions list
https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Let me know if it helps.